# Can Apache Flume Gather data from AWS Kinesis or GCP Pub/Sub?

Tags: hadoop, flume, amazon-kinesis

I am using Flume to gather streaming data from Kafka to HDFS.

But the data source may become multiple.

Therefore, I am wondering if I can build a data gathering system:

Kafka / Kinesis / Pub/Sub -> Flume -> HDFS(Storage) / Flink (Processing).

But it seems that I cannot find data on how to connect Flume to Kinesis, pub/sub. Is this doable? Any help is appreciated.